# Driving me crazy. SETX /?

Tags: cmd.exe, environment-variables

Rosalee is no longer a user, but her name remains everywhere.

I am thinking of exporting the registry and performing a Find/Replace on all Rosalee's or trying to use `setx`, but I cannot figure out the syntax for `setx`.

```
C:\Windows\system32>set
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\Rosalee\AppData\Roaming
COMPUTERNAME=BRIDGEHAMPTON
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Rosalee
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Rosalee\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\BRIDGEHAMPTON


SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\Rosalee\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\Rosalee\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=BRIDGEHAMPTON
USERNAME=Diane
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Rosalee
windir=C:\Windows
```

Comment: Rosalee is the user logged in on the system, which is why the environmental variables still contain her name. Log in as a different user, and they'll be changed automatically by Windows to show that new username. You've just changed the `USERNAME` variable's value, which you shouldn't do.

Comment: Also please note that "renaming" an existing user **does not** rename the username on OS-level. For example it will keep `C:\Users\Rosalee` even if you renamed "Rosalee" to something else. The only way around it would be to create a **new** user and delete the old one. (Is that what you did? Renaming "Rosalee"?)